# Check whether a folder already exists with Bun

Tags: bun

How do I check whether a folder already exists using Bun?

I tried the following without success:

```
const path = "folderName"
const file = Bun.file(path)
await file.exists()
```

Based on the guide for working with files:
https://bun.sh/guides/read-file/exists

I know it's for checking whether a file exists, but usually you can do the same thing for folders.
I checked that the path is correct by referring for a file inside the folder `folderName/fileName`, and it worked.

**How do I check whether a folder already exists with Bun?**

Answer (score 0):

To test if a file/folder exist , you can use :

```
const fExist = path => !! Array.from(
      new Bun.Glob(path).scanSync({ onlyFiles: false })
    )[0]
```

If you want to know if it's a folder and not a file, you can compare with the *scanSync* without option